# GROUP BY en SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Requiero diseñar una consulta SQL que me permita realizar agrupaciones, la tabla de la cual estoy tomando la información es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Query que estoy utilizando:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       CODIGO AS "Código"
FROM   Table
GROUP BY CODIGO;
```

Lo anterior, devuelve:

```
COUNT(*) | Código
5        | ABCD20210716
2        | EFGH20210716
3        | IJKL20210716
```

Sin embargo, requiero que si la columna Day tiene campos repetidos como es el caso de:

1. 16/10/2021 (se encuentra 3 veces).
2. 16/12/2021 (se encuentra 3 veces).

Devuelva un único registro, es decir, algo así:

```
COUNT(*) | Código
5        | ABCD20210716 → Corresponde a la fila 1, 2, 3, 4, 8
1        | IJKL20210716 → Corresponde a la fila 7
```

Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: pero básicamente estás diciendo que el día lo cuentas una sola vez...cómo sabemos si tiene que contarlo en el código ABCD o en otro?, cuál es el criterio?

Comment: @Lamak hola, si está repetido debería contarlo para ABCD20210716

Comment: pero eso quiero saber, con qué criterio se elige eso?, qué pasa cuando sean otros códigos?, no me puedes decir simplemente es el ABCD

Comment: @Lamak el criterio es que, el primer registro que queda en Base de Datos tiene una composición alfanumérica de "ABCDYYYYMMD"

Comment: @Lamak debería primar los primeros 4 caracteres, en orden alfabético: ABCD es primero, EFGH es segundo e IJKL es tercero.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER` previamente para dejar un registro por día, y luego hacer el `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       CODIGO AS "Código"

FROM (  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Day ORDER BY Codigo) AS RN
        FROM Table) t
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY CODIGO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo sencillo para eliminar duplicados tomando el código considerado como mínimo y luego hacer la agregación sobre ese cálculo.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       Codigo  AS "Código"
FROM (
    SELECT DAY,
           MIN(CODIGO) AS "Codigo"
    FROM   Table
    GROUP BY DAY) DC
GROUP BY CODIGO;
```